# In Python, how to overlap histogram graphs about data frame inside one panel?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have a question about overlapping graphs inside one panel in Python.

I generated numbers of two groups

```
import numpy as np
cv1 = np.random.normal(50, 4, 1000)
cv2 = np.random.normal(40, 7, 1000)


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.hist(cv1, numpy.linspace(0, 70, 100))
plt.hist(cv2, numpy.linspace(0, 70, 100))
plt.xlabel("Grain weight (mg)", size=12)
plt.ylabel("Frequency_Histogram", size=12)
plt.show()
```

[image]

It works perfectly. However, if the data is the format of data frame, how can I make the same graph?

For example, I simulated that I have two data set for different genotypes, cv1, cv2. In each data, grain weight for 1,000 grains was measured.

```
cv1_data = {"Genotype": ["cv1"]*1000,"AGW": cv1}
cv1_weight = DataFrame(cv1_data)

cv2_data = {"Genotype": ["cv2"]*1000,"AGW": cv2}
cv2_weight = DataFrame(cv2_data)
```

[image]

Then, I'd like to make the same graph above. So I tried below codes

```
plt.hist(cv1,y="AGW", numpy.linspace(0, 70, 100))
plt.hist(cv2,y="AGW", numpy.linspace(0, 70, 100))
plt.xlabel("Grain weight (mg)", size=12)
plt.ylabel("Frequency_Histogram", size=12)
plt.show()
```

but it does not work. Could you let me know how to make the same overlapping graph in case of data frame?

Always, many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using Seaborn library in python

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns


cv1 = np.random.normal(50, 4, 1000)
cv2 = np.random.normal(40, 7, 1000)

cv1_data = {"Genotype": ["cv1"]*1000,"AGW": cv1}
cv1_weight = pd.DataFrame(cv1_data)

cv2_data = {"Genotype": ["cv2"]*1000,"AGW": cv2}
cv2_weight = pd.DataFrame(cv2_data)

df = pd.concat([cv1_weight,cv2_weight],axis = 1)
df.columns = ['Genotype', 'cv1_AGW', 'Genotype', 'cv2_AGW']

sns.histplot(data = df[['cv1_AGW','cv2_AGW']])
```

Comment: Dear. Yagami, could you let me know how to change y-axis as histogram frequency (%), not the number of observation (in current graph)?

Comment: sns.kdeplot(data = df[['cv1_AGW','cv2_AGW']])

You can use kde plot from seaborn

Comment: Thank you so much!! You're my hero!! I have two more questions. The code you suggested is a curve graph. If I want to maintain histogram, and prefer the y-asix as % (maybe density), how can I do that? If I want have a normal distribution graph (PDF curve), not curve graph (the code you suggested), how can I make it? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: sns.displot(data = df[['cv1_AGW','cv2_AGW']], stat = "probability")

Comment: Thanks!! It's perfect!!! Finally, could you let me know how to make normal distribution graph (PDF curve)? This code, sns.kdeplot(data = df[['cv1_AGW','cv2_AGW']]) is density curve graph. I'd like to know how to make normal distribution graph (the area of graph is 1). Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Iam sorry, Jin. Iam not sure of adding normal curve to the histograms.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Thank to you, today I did learn a lot!! Many thanks!!